# Auto-Detect the Silent Switches for Executable

Tags: powershell

In our environment, we are trying to automate the process of Unattended/Silent Installation for EXE's.
I would like to know, is there a way to auto-detect the silent switches for executables. Is there some way to determine if an EXE has some sort of unattended install support and, if so, get the right argument so I can pass it to the file when I run it? or to get the installer information like if its Installshield, Innosetup or Installanywhere?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

As far I know there is no way to automate it, but you can find common silent arguments based on application installer used here:

http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

Regards,